# Help to find angles of a triangle in L2 space

Tags: functional-analysis

How to find angles of a triangle whose vertices are $x1(t)\equiv0, x2(t)\equiv1$ and $x3(t)=t$ in the space $L_{2}[-1; 1]$ ?

I found norms $\left \| x_{1} \right \| = \sqrt{\int_{-1}^{1}x_{1}^{2}dt} = \sqrt{\int_{-1}^{1}0^{2}dt}=0$ , $\left \| x_{2} \right \| = \sqrt{\int_{-1}^{1}x_{2}^{2}dt} = \sqrt{\int_{-1}^{1}1^{2}dt}=\sqrt{2}$, $\left \| x_{3} \right \| = \sqrt{\int_{-1}^{1}x_{3}^{2}dt} = \sqrt{\int_{-1}^{1}t^{2}dt}=0$

$\left ( x_{1},x_{2} \right ) = \int_{-1}^{1}x_{1}(t)x_{2}(t)dt = 0$,

$\left ( x_{2},x_{3} \right ) = \int_{-1}^{1}x_{2}(t)x_{3}(t)dt = \int_{-1}^{1}tdt=0$,

$\left ( x_{1},x_{3} \right ) = \int_{-1}^{1}x_{1}(t)x_{3}(t)dt = 0$

Where I have mistakes?

Comment: $\int_{-1}^1 t^2 \, dt = \frac23$, not $0$, but that doesn't really help the general issue here.

Comment: You have to consider $x_1-x_2$, $x_2-x_3$, and $x_3-x_1$.  These vectors represent the edges of the triangle

Comment: Why  $x1−x2$, $x2−x3$, and $x3−x1$ will be the edges?